# How to get the file if there is no link

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I was scraping steamdb for a university project, where I was able to get almost every thing using BeatifulSoup and urllib but there is this one thing which I cant get to work because there are no links to it.

There are these charts https://steamdb.info/app/570/graphs/ , when you click on download icon on top right of the graph and select any one download option you can download the file but there are no links in tag info when you do inspect element.

What I found is that there are some onclick event listeners attached to those download div's and traced those functions to this js https://steamdb.info/static/js/vendor/highstock.20180826.js and in this js if you search for "highcharts-menu-item"(which is the class for those download div's) you get exactly 1 match. But I couldn't figure out how that function is producing download item. So can anyone explain how the download magic is happening.

Comment: That code is minified, it's extremely difficult to read and understand.

Comment: `HighCharts`'s library builds the graphs on the fly and creates temporary images *within* the browser --  There are no *physical* files associated with that ...  You're going to need to be able to effectively "run" the JavaScript to get the HighCharts graphs.

Comment: @Barmar you can use this https://www.browserling.com/tools/js-prettify to make the code readable.

Comment: @TubbyStubby That indents it nicely, it's still not understandable with meaningless variable names.

Comment: @Zak they have to giving data to make the graph and that data must be coming from somewhere. Can you figure out where it is coming from??

Comment: @TubbyStubby --  With my installation of HighCharts I use CURL statements directly from my `php`, to my `DB` and then render the page -- So really, if they do it like I do then no, you can't tell where their data is "coming from" --  You can use the "Network" tab in your developer's tools and *hope* they are making an AJAX call that has JSON or something useful you can make use of -- Else you're going to be stuck parsing/running  the JS itself.

Comment: @TubbyStubby -- furthermore -- If you **had** the data in hand .. You still need to **run** HighCharts to *build* the graphs ..  Unless you thought you could build them yourself with the raw data ..

Comment: From the answers bellow I got the all the data necessary to build the graph. The values are stored as key value pairs. Start represents epoch time for where the x-axis starts and steps are 1 day again in epoch time. But still I will try to run the js and get the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the network tab of chrome dev tools to find the following API endpoint (click the 'Response' tab to see the JSON data):
https://steamdb.info/api/GetGraph/?type=concurrent_max&appid=570

Which matches this element:

`<iframe src="https://steamdb.info/embed/?appid=570" height="389px" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

[image: viewing network tab]

```
        a.Chart.prototype.getCSV = function(a) {
        var f = ""
          , h = this.getDataRows()
          , d = this.options.exporting.csv
          , l = m(d.decimalPoint, "," !== d.itemDelimiter && a ? (1.1).toLocaleString()[1] : ".")
          , e = m(d.itemDelimiter, "," === l ? ";" : ",")
          , p = d.lineDelimiter;
        c(h, function(a, d) {
            for (var c, g = a.length; g--; )
                c = a[g],
                "string" === typeof c && (c = '"' + c + '"'),
                "number" === typeof c && "." !== l && (c = c.toString().replace(".", l)),
                a[g] = c;
            f += a.join(e);
            d < h.length - 1 && (f += p)
        });
```

Comment: First of all thanks. Although that is not giving me the xls or csv file but approach given by @Zak and what you found gives the raw data which seems to be readable.

Comment: I made a guess that the data in JSON format would allow you to complete your task.  Further to the answers above, Pretty Print is available in the chrome dev tools, click the `{}` button. 

You can also search this pretty printed code for 'CSV' which will narrow down the CSV file generation. Good Luck :)